# Override Ruby's base C code from Gem

Tags: c, ruby, parsing

For the sake of experimentation, I am looking for a way to modify some of Ruby's base code, specifically the parser. I was wondering if this was possible to do at all, let alone using a Gem.

I have narrowed the code I need to change to `static int yylex()` within `parser.c`. I was going to try to use an alias, but that seems to require that I change `parser.h`, which cannot be done within a Gem, as I understand.

Can this be done from a Gem?

Comment: as far as my understanding of ruby goes, you cannot do this from a Gem since gems run on top the ruby interpretter. you can add c extensions to your gem but you can't affect the interpretter thats already running. 
 for more info on gems with c extensions: http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The only base C code that gems have access to is that exposed by the [Ruby headers](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/include/ruby).
The parsing/lexing code is not exposed there.

If you want to define custom syntax, I would try (in order):

1. Loosen your requirements a bit and define a [DSL](https://www.leighhalliday.com/creating-ruby-dsl). Ruby has insanely powerful metaprogramming features that can take anything you might do statically in a script and instead do it dynamically during runtime
2. Write your custom parser in Ruby and emit valid Ruby which you then `eval`. Ugly, and probably a little slow, but will allow you to do anything you want.
3. Modify the [mruby](https://github.com/mruby/mruby) parser instead. mruby is designed for embedded applications where you want to be able to highly customize the capabilities of the VM. I doubt that they had the parser in mind, but still it might be more feasible than messing around with MRI.

Comment: rats. i was going to try to try to put ++ -- in there, just out of spite. oh well.